# How to achieve the super high contrast look of Thierry Le Gouès' Soul Album?

Tags: photo-editing, portrait, black-and-white, contrast, nude-photography

I'm curious to know how to achieve the high contrast look of Thierry Le Gouès' Soul album (please note: images are NSFW). I know this is probably done in post but I would like to know if there is a particular technique or maybe even an online tutorial to achieve this look.

Comment: For those not familiar with Thierry Le Goues, I do **not** recommend a Google image search at work.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the details, but do not underestimate the power of makeup.

Normally this kind of photos have a lot of pre-production work.

Just a tip, "back in the days" of film photography there was a film called "lith" for example Kodak's Kodalith, that produced a totally contrasted image, with almost no middle tones. This is not the case because you can see clearly gray tones. What you have is a super glossy oily makeup with some good softboxes reflection.

Comment: You mean [this film](https://filmphotographystore.com/products/35mm-bw-film-kodak-kodalith-vintage-stock-1-roll)? The samples aren't as contrasty as you say though, I wonder why. Never tried it myself.